# Como alterar a cor de fundo do PopupMenu?

Tags: android, android-layout

Como alterar a cor de fundo do PopupMenu e setar a altura da sombra. O único resultado que tive foi setando o popupBackgound no styles.xml o problema é que perde a sombra.

API de compatibilidade minSdkVersion 16

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>

    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
      <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Testei também

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O tipo de resource que o *PopupMenu* espera como Background é uma imagem, mais exactamente um [9-Patch bitmap](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html), e não uma *Color*.

Depois de criar o *9-Patch bitmap* que quer utilizar coloque-o na pasta `res\drawable`. Deve, preferencialmente, criar um por cada densidade de tela.

Declare um *style* no arquivo `values\styles.xml` e atribua o *bitmap* ao `popupBackground`.

```
<style name="PopupMenu.Laranja" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_background</item>
</style>
```

No *style* referente ao *theme* da aplicação indique que o *PopupMenu* deve utilizar esse novo *style*.

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Laranja</item>
```

O arquivo `values\styles.xml` ficará assim:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <!-- Style que o popupMenu deve utilizar -->
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Laranja</item>

    </style>

    <!-- Style do popupMenu. -->
    <style name="PopupMenu.Laranja" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/popup_menu_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Para testar use este *9-Patch bitmap*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dê-lhe o nome ***popup_menu_background.9.png*** e coloco-o na pasta `res\drawable`.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Abusando um pouco da sua boa vontade, onde consigo um png desse na cor branca. Tentei alterar o png laranja no Fireworks  mas não ficou bom.

Comment: Uma forma rápida é ir [aqui](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=appcompat&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=f80%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100). Mude a cor de **Popup color** para branco. Faça o *download* do *ZIP* e use o arquivo **menu_dropdown_panel.9.png** que está nas pastas relativas às diferentes densidades.